# context menu in the middle of svg document

Tags: html, svg

I want to know if it is feasible to create a context menu an svg document like this:

[image]

I have the hexagons created how would you create the context menu and specifically the menu items.

How would you know which menu item was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question: In SVG you can use the `<a>` element to create a link:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;font-size:10px}
a{fill:black;}
a:hover text{fill:blue;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="-30 -30 160 60" >
<polygon  id="theHex"  points="21.651,-12.500 21.651,12.500 0.000,25.000 -21.651,12.500 -21.651,-12.500 -0.000,-25.000"></polygon>
  
  <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="#">
    <text x="40" y="-18">Edit owner</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="#">
    <text x="40" y="-3">Conduct BIA</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="#">
    <text x="40" y="12">Assign BIA</text>
  </a> 
  <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="#">
    <text x="40" y="27">Delete</text>
  </a>  
</svg>
```